# Build static library only using Gradle

Tags: c, gradle, build, linker, native

I am building a C project using Gradle, which includes sqlite3 as a native dependency. I would like to build only the static library as I do not need the shared library(.so). In the Gradle documentation it states that both are built by default, but not how to only build one or the other. I have tried including `buildable = false` for the appropriate binary types, but this results in an error. I have attached my build.gradle below. I know this issue isn't breaking anything, but it is really bugging me, because this is going to be a big waste of build time as the project gets bigger moving forward.

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated!

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
        sqlite3(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources.c {
                source {
                    srcDir "lib/sqlite3"
                    include "*.c"
                }
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "lib/sqlite3"
                    include "*.h"
            }
        }
        // Attempted to make the shared Library unbuildable, but this results in a model error!
//          binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) { 
//              buildable = false
//          }
        }
        main(NativeExecutableSpec){
            sources.c {
                source{
                    srcDir "src"
                    include "**/*.c"
                }
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "inc"
                }
            }

            binaries.all {
                lib library: 'sqlite3', linkage: 'static'
                linker.args '-ldl', '-pthread', '-lpam', '-lgnutls', '-lgcrypt', '-levent'
            }
        }
    }

    toolChains {
        clang(Clang)
    }

    tasks {
        run(Task) {
            dependsOn 'build'
            doLast() {
                mkdir('build/run')
                println(' --- BEGIN OUTPUT ---\n')
                exec {
                    executable '../binaries/mainExecutable/main'
                    workingDir './build/run'
                }
                println('\n --- END OUTPUT ---')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you write "but this results in an error" what is the error, where is the error, and have you Googled the error?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to reproduce the error for @nicomp, and it fixed itself. The only difference is that I have since updated Gradle, so it seems to have been a bug in the still experimental native code support of Gradle.

Just for the record, the original error said something along the lines that the model was in an unmodifiable state. According to Google that's supposed to happen when you try and modify the model during task execution. This drove me nuts, because I that's not what I was doing.

Thanks to everyone that had a look!